# How do I hide the 'Edit' link in publshed posts

Tags: links

I've noticed that the 'Edit' link is being displayed at the foot of my published pages. Clearly, this is undesirable because it allows readers to edit the posts.

How do I remove the Edit link from the options in the Admin area?

Comment: showing a link does not allow anybody to edit posts.  this is not how the internet works thankfully.

Comment: This will only show for logged in users.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** links only shown to those who are *logged in* and has *post editing capability*. Seems you're logged in as an admin. Readers cannot edit your post unless the reader is logged in and has post editing capability.

Adding the edit link to the post is a theme specific feature. Usually, theme author implements this feature. So, you cannot hide/remove it from dashboard/admin panel. You have to edit the theme templates to hide/remove the link.